# Shell script using for loop for executing different variables on each iteration

Tags: shell

I am trying to iterate nested for each loop in a shell script which is giving the expected results but along with extra output.

Below is the code.

```
 for container in ${DB_1} ${DB_2}
 do
 for container_dump in ${DB_1_bkup} ${db_2bkup}
 do
    echo "${container} and backups/${container_dump}_dump_`date +%Y-%m-%d"_"%H_%M_%S`.dump"
  done
done
```

What output I am getting is.

```
DB_1 and backups/DB_1_bkup_dump_`date +%Y-%m-%d"_"%H_%M_%S`.dump
DB_1 and backups/DB_2_bkup_dump_`date +%Y-%m-%d"_"%H_%M_%S`.dump
DB_2 and backups/DB_1_bkup_dump_`date +%Y-%m-%d"_"%H_%M_%S`.dump
DB_2 and backups/DB_2_bkup_dump_`date +%Y-%m-%d"_"%H_%M_%S`.dump
```

What I am expecting is

```
DB_1 and backups/DB_1_bkup_dump_`date +%Y-%m-%d"_"%H_%M_%S`.dump
DB_2 and backups/DB_2_bkup_dump_`date +%Y-%m-%d"_"%H_%M_%S`.dump
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your question, you don't need two nested loops...
Just get the container name from the bkup variable...

```
for container_dump in ${DB_1_bkup} ${db_2bkup}
do
    if [ "${container_dump}" = "${DB_1_bkup}" ]; then
        container=${DB_1}
    else
        container=${DB_2}
    fi
    echo "${container} and backups/${container_dump}_dump_`date +%Y-%m-%d"_"%H_%M_%S`.dump"
done
```